# Webdriver Sampler not working with JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Am trying to automate one of my application using web driver sampler with JMeter but getting error (please check below). Tried with Chrome, Chromium & Gecko driver.

Version of Tool:

1. JMeter : 5.3
2. Java Version : java version "17.0.6" 2023-01-17 LTS
3. Chrome driver : 120 as the chrome version of the system is 120.0 (driver catalog : https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable)
4. Web Driver Version : 4.13.0

Sample Code inside the web driver sampler with scripting language (beanshell although tried with JAVA and Groovy, observed same error):

```
var driverHandler = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium, org.openqa.selenium.support.ui);
var sleepSynchronizer = new driverHandler.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 5000);

driverHandler.sampleResult.sampleStart();
//Render the home Page
WDS.browser.get('<application URL>');
sleepSynchronizer.until(driverHandler.ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(sleepSynchronizer.By.id('details-button')));

//Handling Cookies
var sessionCOOKIES = WDS.browser.manage().getCookies();
WDS.vars.putObject('cookies', sessionCOOKIES)
java.lang.Thread.sleep(6000);
```

**Error while using Chrome Driver:**

```
2024-01-13 19:55:24,522 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Thread Group 1-1,6,main]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient$Factory.createClient(NettyClient.java:124) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.13.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:115) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.13.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:92) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.13.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.<init>(DriverCommandExecutor.java:89) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.13.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriverCommandExecutor.<init>(ChromiumDriverCommandExecutor.java:43) ~[selenium-chromium-driver-4.13.0.jar:?]
```

**Error while using Firefox(Gecko) Driver:**

```
2024-01-13 19:37:27,069 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Thread Group 1-1,6,main]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient$Factory.createClient(NettyClient.java:124) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.13.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:115) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.13.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:92) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.13.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.<init>(DriverCommandExecutor.java:89) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.13.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver$FirefoxDriverCommandExecutor.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:415) ~[selenium-firefox-driver-4.13.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.generateExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:147) ~[selenium-firefox-driver-4.13.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:132) ~[selenium-firefox-driver-4.13.0.jar:?]
```

**Error while using Chromium Driver:**

*Note:* In chromium the browser is launching with the following error,

```
2024-01-13 19:38:16,709 ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Error calling threadStarted
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '4.13.0', revision: 'ba948ece5b*'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.6'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:248) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.13.0.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.ChromeDriverConfig.getThreadService(ChromeDriverConfig.java:47) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.13.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.ChromeDriverConfig.createBrowser(ChromeDriverConfig.java:26) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.13.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.ChromeDriverConfig.createBrowser(ChromeDriverConfig.java:14) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.13.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.getPreparedBrowser(WebDriverConfig.java:221) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.13.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.threadStarted(WebDriverConfig.java:152) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.13.0.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread$ThreadListenerTraverser.addNode(JMeterThread.java:769) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
```

Is there any way to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you don't have [selenium-remote-driver.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-remote-driver/4.13.0) in your [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath), in other words your WebDriver Sampler installation is broken.

Either download the above jar, drop it to "lib" folder of your JMeter installation and restart JMeter or (better)

1. Install fresh [JMeter 5.6.3](https://lists.apache.org/thread/o906of55x1n8z2zm8fyj3w9k3lqf8y0c) (as per [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-memory-profiling) article you should be using the latest version of JMeter)
2. Install [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)
3. Install WebDriver Sampler using JMeter Plugins Manager
4. Either downgrade to JDK < 15 or switch to Groovy language because [JavaScript engine support has been removed from JDK15](https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/2365)

Comment: Actually I should have updated my question the remote driver is present in the location, though I will try with 5.6.3